# how to change the id color based on the date of today

Tags: javascript, date, colors, get

this is what i have:

```
<div class="listWeek">
   <a href="#" onclick="showMaa();"  id="MaaKnop">Mo</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showDin();"  id="DinKnop">Tu</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showWoe();"  id="WoeKnop">We</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showDon();"  id="DonKnop">Th</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showVri();"  id="VriKnop">Vr</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showZat();"  id="ZatKnop">Sa</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showZon();"  id="ZonKnop">Su</a>
</div>
```

i want to change the color of the day based on today's day.

Comment: please share the script functions also

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listWeek">
 <a href="#" data-val="1" id="MaaKnop">Mo</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="2" id="DinKnop">Tu</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="3" id="WoeKnop">We</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="4" id="DonKnop">Th</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="5" id="VriKnop">Vr</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="6" id="ZatKnop">Sa</a>
 <a href="#" data-val="0" id="ZonKnop">Su</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var date = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].getAttribute("data-val") == date.getDay()) {
        s[i].style.color = "red"
    }
}
```

1. I have use custom **`data-*`** attribute
2. **`date.getDay()`** returns current day as number range starts 0 - 6, based on that I have devised the code.
3. Get the list of a tags, and iterate it.  Once it find the current day matches change the color.

Hope you understood.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8e5w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you should have tried something before asking.. anyway, this is a fast-n-dirty way to do it

```
var days = ['MaaKnop', 'DinKnop', 'WoeKnop', 'DonKnop', 'VriKnop', 'ZatKnop', 'ZonKnop'];

var current_day = new Date().getDay();

document.getElementById(days[current_day - 1]).style.color = "#f00";

// or you could add a css class
document.getElementById(days[current_day - 1]).className = "active";

.active{
    color: red;
}
```